# How do I stop image from uploading when form fields are empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a back end form that allows me to upload images and input values into form fields. If any form fields are empty, when trying to upload an image, an error message should display next to the empty form field. The image should not be able to upload until all form fields contain a value. For some reason, the error message is displaying not to fields before the add button is click. The only form field I don't want required, is the link form field. How do I stop image from uploading if form field is empty?

This is the code of index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values

$nameErr = $videoErr = $LinkErr = $captionErr = "";

$name = $video = $Link = $caption = "";

//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["video"])) {
    $videoErr = "video is required";
  } else {
    $video = test_input($_POST["video"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Link"])) {
    $Link = "";
  } else {
    $Link = test_input($_POST["Link"]);
  }



  if (empty($_POST["caption"])) {
    $captionErr = "caption is required";
  } else {
    $caption = test_input($_POST["caption"]);
  }


function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Upload porn thumbnail and video</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="insert.php">
  <label for="video">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if (!empty($name)) echo $name; ?>" />
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span><br><br>
    <label for="video">Video:</label>
    <input type="text" id="video" name="video" value="<?php if (!empty($video)) echo $video; ?>" />
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $videoErr;?></span><br><br>
    <label for="Link">Link:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Link" name="Link" value="<?php if (!empty($Link)) echo $Link; ?>" />
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $LinkErr;?></span><br><br>
    <label for="Caption">Caption:</label>
    <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" value="<?php if (!empty($caption)) echo $caption; ?>" />
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $captionErr;?></span><br><br>
    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />

    <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
  </form>





</body>
</html>
```

This is the code to insert.php:

```
<?php
require_once('appvars.php');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'image_display'))
{
echo 'Database not selected';
}

    @$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['name']));
    $caption = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['caption']));
    $Link = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Link']));
    $video = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['video']));
    $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_FILES['image']['name']));
    $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size']; 



if (!empty($caption) && !empty($image)) {
      if ((($image_type == 'image/gif') || ($image_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($image_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($image_type == 'image/png'))
        && ($image_size > 0) && ($image_size <= TN_MAXFILESIZE)) {
        if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
          // Move the file to the target upload folder
          $target = TN_UPLOADPATH . $image;
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            // Write the data to the database
            @$query = "INSERT INTO table1(image1,name,imagelink,caption,video) VALUES ('$image', '$name', '$link', '$caption', '$video')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            // Confirm success with the user
            echo '<p>Thanks for adding your new image</p>';
            //echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $name . '<br />';
            //echo '<strong>Score:</strong> ' . $score . '<br />';
            echo '<img src="' . TN_UPLOADPATH . $image . '" alt="" /></p>';
            echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to page</a></p>';

            // Clear  form
            $name = "";
            $caption = "";
            $Link = "";
            $video = "";
            $image = "";

            mysqli_close($conn);
          }
          else {
            echo '<p class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your screen shot image.</p>';
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        echo '<p class="error">The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than ' . (TN_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' file size is too big.</p>';
      }

      // Try to delete the temporary image file
      @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    }
    else {
      echo '<p class="error">Please enter all of the information to add file.</p>';
    }



?>
```

Comment: Remember, PHP is server-side, you need to do some validations in client-side. You can use jquery and https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: html5 has a `required` attribute for this on inputs.

Comment: You could also hook into `form.onsubmit`, and if the form is not valid, return `false`. This will prevent the submission of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make validation in insert.php , Move validation code on insert.php and only upload if validation is ok.

```
<?php
 // define variables and set to empty values

 $nameErr = $videoErr = $LinkErr = $captionErr = "";

 $name = $video = $Link = $caption = "";

//if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
 } else {
  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
 }

 if (empty($_POST["video"])) {
 $videoErr = "video is required";
} else {
 $video = test_input($_POST["video"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["Link"])) {
  $Link = "";
} else {
  $Link = test_input($_POST["Link"]);
}



if (empty($_POST["caption"])) {
 $captionErr = "caption is required";
} else {
 $caption = test_input($_POST["caption"]);
}
 require_once('appvars.php');

 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";

 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,'image_display'))
  {
  echo 'Database not selected';
  }

@$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['name']));
$caption = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['caption']));
$Link = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Link']));
$video = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['video']));
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_FILES['image']['name']));
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size']; 



  if (!empty($caption) && !empty($image)) {
  if ((($image_type == 'image/gif') || ($image_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($image_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($image_type == 'image/png'))
    && ($image_size > 0) && ($image_size <= TN_MAXFILESIZE)) {
    if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
      // Move the file to the target upload folder
      $target = TN_UPLOADPATH . $image;
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        // Write the data to the database
        @$query = "INSERT INTO table1(image1,name,imagelink,caption,video) VALUES ('$image', '$name', '$link', '$caption', '$video')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        // Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>Thanks for adding your new image</p>';
        //echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $name . '<br />';
        //echo '<strong>Score:</strong> ' . $score . '<br />';
        echo '<img src="' . TN_UPLOADPATH . $image . '" alt="" /></p>';
        echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to page</a></p>';

        // Clear  form
        $name = "";
        $caption = "";
        $Link = "";
        $video = "";
        $image = "";

        mysqli_close($conn);
      }
      else {
        echo '<p class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your screen shot image.</p>';
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<p class="error">The screen shot must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than ' . (TN_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) . ' file size is too big.</p>';
  }

  // Try to delete the temporary image file
  @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
}
else {
  echo '<p class="error">Please enter all of the information to add file.</p>';
}


  function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }
 ?>
```